# PerformSelector is secretly invoked in target-action cases?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

In this example, the function I pass to selector is invoked by calling performSelector secretly?

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionGesture(gesture: )))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func actionGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
....
}
```

Comment: secretly? what do you mean? it is called when the pan gesture is getting triggered. no secret :D

Comment: I mean performSelector is called or not. I am trying to understand how my function is invoked.

Comment: yes, it will be called on pan

Comment: Thank you. It cleared :)